# HTML: Images in columns

Tags: html, css

How can I produce an HTML/CSS layout similar to this working example: http://mythoughtswouldscareyou.tumblr.com/

I basically want to replicate this general layout. I've tried using `<li>` with a `float: left;` attribute, but I know this is not the way to go.

Just a basic outline/explanation of an efficient way to do this would help me out a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, there are tools for this:

http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

> Masonry is a dynamic grid layout plugin for jQuery. Think of it as the
>   flip-side of CSS floats. Whereas floating arranges elements
>   horizontally then vertically, Masonry arranges elements vertically,
>   positioning each element in the next open spot in the grid. The result
>   minimizes vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like
>   a mason fitting stones in a wall.

Answer (score 1):

The website you mentioned uses [jQuery.masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). With images of varying heights and a bunch of `float: left` elements you'll usually end up with blocks that do not align with each other all too well. This plugin arranges such elements intelligently makes best use of available space and eliminates as many gaps as possible.